# SQL to JSON, ORM for PHP 7 and Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, orm

I am working on a REST API where I have to query information and return a proper JSON object. I am looking for PHP/Laravel libraries which can do the job easily.

A normal SQL query with table JOINs gives me rows of information

`SQL`:

```
    SELECT H.fname AS `fname`,
    H.sname AS `sname`,
    S.id AS `students.id`,
    A.topic AS `students.tasks.topic`,
    A.wordcount AS `students.tasks.wordcount`
    FROM `humans` AS `H`
    LEFT JOIN `students` AS `S` ON H.id = S.human
    LEFT JOIN `courses` AS `C` ON S.course = C.id
    LEFT JOIN `tasks` AS `T` ON T.student = S.id
    LEFT JOIN `assignments` AS `A` ON T.assignment = A.id
    WHERE H.email = "user@email.com"
```

The response rows encoded in JSON:

```
[
    {
        "fname": "Donnie",
        "sname": "Ashok",
        "students.id": "987152e7b3056f1b96c964614b0b6328",
        "students.tasks.topic": "How to dismantle an Anti-matter injector manifold? ",
        "students.tasks.wordcount": 1500
    },
    {
        "fname": "Donnie",
        "sname": "Ashok",
        "students.id": "987152e7b3056f1b96c964614b0b6328",
        "students.tasks.topic": "How to intercept sub-space transmission using Dilithium Matrices? ",
        "students.tasks.wordcount": 1500
    },
    {
        "fname": "Donnie",
        "sname": "Ashok",
        "students.id": "3ea4f7b2e1e4bcc26ae544dd14d107fe",
        "students.tasks.topic": null,
        "students.tasks.wordcount": null
    }
]
```

However, I need something like a proper JSON object like this:

```
[
    {
        "fname": "Donnie",
        "sname": "Ashok",
        "students": [
            {
                "id": "987152e7b3056f1b96c964614b0b6328",
                "tasks": [
                    {
                        "topic": "How to intercept sub-space transmission using Dilithium Matrices? ",
                        "wordcount": 1500
                    },
                    {
                        "topic": "How to dismantle an Anti-matter injector manifold?",
                        "wordcount": 1500
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "3ea4f7b2e1e4bcc26ae544dd14d107fe",
                "tasks": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there any PHP library or ORM which I can use to organise the SQL rows?

Comment: You can do it with Laravel Eloquent if you don't use the plain SQL Statement. Eloquent will return you the result the way you want,Or you may use Fractal : https://fractal.thephpleague.com/simple-example/ , that might fulfill your desired result.

Comment: Use spatie-fractalistic.

Comment: http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=2cb5e4c4375e4291ad87cd9583ae69e8

This is the outcome with Fractal. As I need JSON data with high depth, this does not seem to be what I need.

I will try Eloquent, is there anything you recommend that can help me to get started with?

Comment: Using Laravel 5.5 Resources to create your own {JSON:API} formatted API 
In Laravel 5.5 we now have Resource classes we can use for our APIs out of the box without having to install any 3rd party packages.
Using eloquent Resource class is a way to transform data from one format to another.

Answer (score 0):

I use [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) specification for APIs, and I think it's good to use. it's a commonly used specification.
To implement one could use [nilportugues/laravel5-jsonapi](https://github.com/nilportugues/laravel5-jsonapi) package.

Have a look at [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) as well. It is a query language for APIs. [Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql](https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql) is a package for implementing GraphQL.

Both of these would make you APIs data format clear.

JsonAPI sample data

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "To TDD or Not"
    }
  }
}
```

GraphQL sample data

```
{
  "data": {
    "human": {
      "name": "Luke Skywalker",
      "height": 1.72
    }
  }
}
```

As others mentioned in the comments php league's  [fractal](https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal) is an excellent option too.

Hope this helps